# SQL Query too slow on second pc

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

We have a huge database with over 100 tables and millions of rows.
I created a stored procedure for a job, tested it local and got 500'000 results in less than 10sec. I tested the same query on a second pc and waited about 1 hours for the same result.

The simple version of the query is:

```
select * from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.Table2Id = Table2.Id
where Table1.Segment = @segment
```

Table1 38'553'864 Rows
Table2 10'647'167 Rows

I used the execution plan and got the following result:

[image]

On the local PC I got the result:

[image]

(I could send the whole execution plan if needed)

The second PC is a virtual Server(testystem). It has a lot more memory, more space... I also stopped every Job on the server and only tried the sql query, but got the same result. So there aren't any sql query which blocks the tables.

Later I created a Index on the foreign key of table1 and tried to use it, but can't improve the query.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be and how I could solve it?

Comment: look like the statistics needs an update

Comment: If you call this query in your local system more often, the statistics and maybe cached plans ans results can highly influence the speed. As a second effect by usage of shared memory this might work on a local system much faster (but not **that** much).

Comment: Please provide your execution plan for both queries (`*.sqlplan`)

Answer (score 0):

It would take a while to create a execution plan for both querys. But here are a few steps, who already helped a lot. Thanks guys for your help.

The statistics on the tables are from september last year on the second PC. We don't use the query that much on the server. An update on the statistics is a good point.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397(v=sql.120).aspx

Another thing is to improve my sql query. I removed the where and add it as a condition on the first inner join. So it filter the rows in the first table and after join the huge amount of rows from the second. (The where filters about 90% of the first table and table 3 is really small)

```
select * from Table1
inner join Table3 on Table1.Segment = @segment
     and Table1.Table3Id = Table3.Id
inner join Table2 on Table1.Table2Id = Table2.Id
```

A next step is. I created an SQL Job which rebuild all Indexes. So they are up to date.

It already a lot better, but I'm still open for other inputs.

Comment: "I removed the where and add it as a condition on the first inner join"

I am not sure about that, how complex is your query

Comment: I tried it, and the performance improved. two iner join, two left join and one where clause.

Comment: however you have slove the problem, but it would be great if you show actual Execution plan somewhere.